# Which form is more idiomatic Elixir?

Tags: elixir

When writing a method, is it more idiomatic Elixir to provide a default argument in Elixir like so:

`def mktempfile(ext \\ ".log", path) do`

or is it better to have two function definitions one:

`def mktempfile(ext, path) do`

and another

`def mktempfile(path) do`

where the second second definition, where ext is not provided will assume that ext is of a default value. If so, can someone explain why ?

Answer (score 4):

The more idiomatic would be:

```
def mktempfile(path, ext \\ ".log")
```